# Filter base on text input

Tags: jquery

I have a input text for the user enter a text and based on what the user enters in the input field I want to hide in the ol the books (li) that dont have the title or author like the text the user enter in the input text.

```
<form>  
    <input type=" text" id="search">
  </form>
```

List of books

```
<section id="books">    <ol>
    <li class="book"><p><span class="title">Book 1</span>&ensp;<span class="author">Author 1</span></p></li>

    <li class="book"><p><span class="title">Book 2</span>&ensp;<span class="author">Author 2</span></p></li>

    ....    </ol> </section>
```

With this the title shows the text, for example "Book 1 Author 1". But do you know how to properly filter the list items based on the text entered in the input text?

```
function filterBooks(){

    var search = $("#search").val();

    $("#books li").each(function(){

        var title = $(this).text();


    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working solution:

```js
function filterBooks(){
    var search = $("#search").val();
    $("#books li").each(function(){
        var title = $(this).text();
        if (search.length > 0) {
          if (title.includes(search)) {
            $(this).show();
          } else {
            $(this).hide();
          }
        } else {
          $(this).show();
        }
    });
}

$("#search").keyup(function() {
  filterBooks();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>  
    <input type=" text" id="search">
  </form>
  
  <section id="books">    <ol>
    <li class="book"><p><span class="title">Book 1</span>&ensp;<span class="author">Author 1</span></p></li>

    <li class="book"><p><span class="title">Book 2</span>&ensp;<span class="author">Author 2</span></p></li>
</ol> </section>
```

Comment: To make it case insensitive and a bit more versatile, you can match the lowercase values using `.toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the substring of your input exists in your book list you can use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). Then show and hide your desired elements with [`show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/#show) and [`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide).

So your code should be something like this:

```js
function filterBooks() {
  var search = event.target.value;
  $("#books li").each(function() {
    if (search) {
      var title = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      if (title.includes(search)) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
}

$('#search').keyup(filterBooks)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="search">
</form>

<section id="books">
  <ol>
    <li class="book">
      <p><span class="title">Book 1</span>&ensp;<span class="author">Author 1</span></p>
    </li>
    <li class="book">
      <p><span class="title">Book 2</span>&ensp;<span class="author">Author 2</span></p>
    </li>
    <li class="book">
      <p><span class="title">Magazine 1</span></p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.includes` method JS offers for strings and use jquery's `.hide()` to set the list items the user does not want to see as hidden:

```js
function filterBooks() {
  var search = $("#search").val();

  $("#books li").each(function(){
    var title = $(this).text();
    if (title.includes() == false) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<form>  
  <input type=" text" id="search">
</form>

<section id="books">    
  <ol>
    <li class="book"><p><span class="title">Book 1</span>&ensp;<span class="author">Author 1</span></p></li>
    <li class="book"><p><span class="title">Book 2</span>&ensp;<span class="author">Author 2</span></p></li>
  </ol>
</section>
```